# Surjective/ Injective (but NOT bijective) Linear transformations: Range of a subspace is not necessarily a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'll post the full question for context. Please note that the bold is my own addition to the question and the subject of this post. I've tried playing with a few counter-examples but gotten nowhere.

> Let ${T : V \to W}$ be an isomorphism where ${V, W}$ are
>   finite-dimensional and ${V_0}$ is a subspace of ${V}$. Prove that
>   ${R(T(V_0)})$ is a subspace of ${W}$ and $\mathrm{rank}({T(V_0)) =
>  \dim (V_0)}$. **Show why the former statement is not necessarily true if
>   ${T}$ is only strictly surjective or injective (but not bijective and
>   invertible).**
>
> If ${T}$ is bijective, ${T}$ is invertible and ${T^{-1}: W \to V}$ is
>   bijective. We wish to show that ${T^{-1}}: {W}_0 \to {V}_0$ is
>   bijective for some subspace ${W}_0$; then by invertibilty we can
>   conclude ${T}: {V}_0 \mapsto {W}_0$ is bijective. Hence ${R(T(V}_0)) =
> > {W_0}$ and $\mathrm{rank}({T(V_0))} = \dim ({V_0)}$.
>
> By surjectivity, for any $v \in {V}$ there is $w \in {W}$ such that
>   ${T^{-1}}(w) = v$ and by injectivity $w$ is unique. Then for all $v
> > \in {V_0}$ let corresponding $w$ be in subset ${W_0}$. Thus ${T^{-1} :
> > {W_0} \to {V_0}}$ is bijective. $0 \in {W_0}$ since there must be some
>   unique $w$ such that ${T^{-1}}(w) = 0$, and since ${T}$ is linear this
>   must be zero. Again by linearity, the other conditions that determine
>   a subspace are met. Hence ${W_0}$ is a subspace.

Comment: What do you denote $\color{red}R(T(V_0))$?

Comment: That denotes the range of T with domain V_0

Comment: No, it's been fixed to equality.

Comment: But that is altogether $T(V_0)$!

Comment: Why do you talk about rank of $T(V_0)$, but about the dimension of $V_0$? Shouldn't both be dimension?

Comment: That's correct, Bernard. I suspect that this is a teaching exercise in which that reaization is one of the things the students are supposed to grasp while working on it.

Comment: The range of a subspace *is* a subspace; the statement in the title is incorrect.

Comment: I suspect that it should be $rank (\left. T \right|_{V_0})$, i.e.the rank of the restricted map.

Comment: I am confused. If $T$ is linear, $T(V_0)$ will be a subspace. If $T$ is, moreover, injective, then $\text{rank}(T(V_0))=\dim(V_0)$. (In other words, you can find a counterexample only if $T$ is not injective, and the counterexample will be only for the part of the statement that talks about dimensions.)

Comment: If $T$ is surjective but not injective, then you should be able to find an easy example of a subspace $V_0$ of $V$ such that $T(V_0)$ has dimension strictly smaller than that of $V_0$. If $T$ is injective but not surjective, though, the image always has the same dimension.